# SQL group by bit set?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, bit

Is there any way of grouping the results of a select by individual bits set in a column? That is, ignoring combinations of various bits (otherwise a simple `group by column` would suffice).

For example, assuming a table has the values 1 through 10 for the group-by column exactly once (presented below with binary representation to simplify the construction/verification of the following group-by statement result):

```
 1 0001
 2 0010
 3 0011
 4 0100
 5 0101
 6 0110
 7 0111
 8 1000
 9 1001
10 1010
```

the group-by effect I want to achieve would look like:

```
select <bit>, count(*), group_concat(<column>) from <table> group by <...>

0    5    1,3,5,7,9
1    5    2,3,6,7,10
2    4    4,5,6,7
3    3    8,9,10
```

assuming the first bit is "bit 0".

I'm using MySQL at the moment, so ideally a solution should work there; but I'd be interested in other RDBMS solutions, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to split the values up and then reaggregate.  Something like this:

```
select n.n, group_concat(col1)
from t join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
     ) n
     on (1 << n) & bits > 0
group by n;
```

Comment: What does (1 << n) do?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for :) To simplify for the use-case with many more bits, I replaced the inner select with an actual table with values 0-63, (could've used a view too). Thanks!

Comment: @P.Salmon `1<<n` does the same as in most c-like programming languages: shifts `1` to the left by `n`, effectively the same as `2^n` (`2` to the power of `n`). the `n` comes from the values `0, 1, 2, 3` generated by the inner select, which covers the bits I was interested in, in my example from the question. The shifting is necessary to create a `bit-mask` with which to `bitwise-and` the column whose values I'm trying to group.

Comment: C is not one of my languages but thanks for the explanation - i've never come across it's implementation in a sql like language